# Not storing the EditText vlaue in a string

Tags: android

I am having a problem in storing a Edit able Text value in a string. I just want to store a value that user enter store it in some variable. i used toast just after storing a value to check whether the value is store in it or not and toast doesn't show any value. i try the following code but didnt find it helpful.

```
    package com.example.electropollsys;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class CreateAcc extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,  
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     setContentView(R.layout.create_acc);

     final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent i = new Intent(CreateAcc.this, SignIn.class);
            i.addFlags(
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
         }


     });

     final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            public void onClick(View v){

                EditText input1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname1); 
                String fname = input1.getEditableText().toString();

                EditText input2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname1); 
                String lname = input2.getEditableText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+fname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+lname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

              }
         });
    }
    }
```

Comment: you should have edit your previous equestion...instead of posting new one

Comment: add show() at the end of the toast message

Comment: i don't know y was that nothing editing there.. so that y i posted a new question..

Comment: in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713980/value-of-edittext-is-always-empty) question u are saying u are getting empty string in Toast , friend toast is not appear on screen how you are getting empty toast

Comment: this is your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713980/value-of-edittext-is-always-empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+fname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+lname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Toasts do not show unless the `show()` method is called. the `makeText()` method returns a Toast object which you must use to display the toast.

You normally get a lint warning about this, but you seem to have suppressed it with `@SuppressLint("ShowToast")`.

Comment: @user2044144 Please mark this as the solution by clicking the tick mark then

Answer (score 0):

You did like way.

```
Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+fname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Using this its initiate the toast object and return the object but to show the toast notification you need to call show method on that object.

Instead of this write this.

```
Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+fname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

OR

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CreateAcc.this,"...."+fname+"...." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add .show() at the end.

Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/showing-toast-in-android/